# How to redirect to new site using an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my code so far:

```
let cities = ["Bhutan", "London", "Paris", "Dubai", "New York City", "Singapore"];
let show = cities[Math.floor(Math.random() * cities.length)];
  function myCities (){
  if (cities[1]);
    location.assign("https://www.google.com/");
  }
```

So far, I do get a random value from my array as intended. However, I want redirect to a site based off of whatever random value I get. How would I go about this?

Comment: What sort of URL do you want based on the array element?

Comment: I know I have it on google.com but I'm going to change it to redirect to an HTML file. I haven't finished setting up those HTML files, so I'm just using Google as a test run.

Comment: It is hard to answer your question unless you specify what format of URL you want based on the array.

Comment: I want to have it as "location.href("Bhutan.html");" since my HTML files are what I want to redirect to on my final product

Answer (score 0):

Append `.html` to the random array element and set that as the URL.

```js
location.assign(show + '.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

***Observation :*** No need to put a condition for `cities[1]` as it will always work for the element at index 1 in cities array. For random city, you can just normally make the `url` by appending it.

You can try this way **:**

```js
let cities = ["Bhutan", "London", "Paris", "Dubai", "New York City", "Singapore"];

function loadLocationData() {
    let show = cities[Math.floor(Math.random() * cities.length)];
  location.assign(`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/${show}`);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="loadLocationData()">Load Cities</button>
```